# Visual Studio 2013 Update setup blocked

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I was installing Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Update 2, but i got the following error: "Update 2 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer." I was performing a clean installation; there was no previous version of Visual Studio on this computer.

Can anyone help regarding this? Screen shot: 
[image]

Comment: Are you running it under administrator account ? Every time I update my Visual Studio I sign out of my User Account and sign-in in a Administrator Account and then run the update.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is the package you're trying to install is **just** the Update. You want to either install "Visual Studio 2013" and then install the update or install the "Visual Studio 2013 **with** Update 2" package.

Comment: nope..it's not just the update file.. it's the whole 3gb iso file

Comment: Can you share the log file it refers to in the dialog?

Comment: For other people - I got this error with VS 2013 ultimate of which someone named the Update as VS 2013 , so I got the message about Update 5 `does not apply`    Thus I had to find either the Base product only or VS 2013 WITH update 5